# Why scrollbars appear, when I resize the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, document-body

I made a page, where the canvas should fill the window. It works, but for some reason scrollbars appear. I don't know, what is the error.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      #canvas {
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
      }
      * {
        margin: 0px;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function getSize() {
        var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
        if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
          //Non-IE
          myWidth = window.innerWidth;
          myHeight = window.innerHeight;
        } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
          //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
          myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
          myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth ||          document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
          //IE 4 compatible
          myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
          myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        }
        return {x:myWidth,y:myHeight};
      }

      window.onload = function () {
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var size = getSize();
        canvas.width = size.x;
        canvas.height = size.y;
      };
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching #canvas to a block did the trick for me:

```css
#canvas {
    display: block;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

Comment: In particular, a canvas is an inline element, so it has a baseline, just like all other inline elements. So the code creates a canvas the size of the window, but that has to sit on the baseline, which is above the bottom of the block. In this case changing the vertical alignment of the canvas would also have worked, but the `display: block;` is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

It was likely a problem with your CSS.

I moved the 'all elements' up to the top, and made the canvas absolutely positioned just to be safe.

Let me know if this works:

```
<style type="text/css">
          * {
              margin: 0px;
              padding:0px;
          }
          #canvas {
              position:absolute;
              left:0px;
              top:0px;
              background-color: #EEEEEE;
          }

</style>
```